# How to Compile Sass with koala and link it in the index.html

Tags: sass

I'm learning sass. And am using koala to compile a main.scss file to main.css.file But all of my styles are not reflecting on the webpage. Maybe am getting something wrong

//This is part of the scss file

```
.navbar-brand{
  color: $nav-color;
  font-family: $nav-font;
}
```

//And this is how i linked the compiled css file in my index.html

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="styelsheet" href="css/main.css">
<title>Just Sass</title>
```

The main.css is the compiled file.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass?  Did you compile it?  Did you look at the generated output to see if it contained what you were expecting?

Comment: @cimmanon. Ya, i compiled it but it didnt generate any ouput. The entire webpage was just left unstyled. I have a main.scss file and its been compiled to main.css using koala.